# How to return pull request url when commit changes to github using Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, pull-request

When I push a new branch to GitHub from eclipse, a URL is displayed within the output that can be copied to quickly open a new pull request.

[image]

Is it possible to get this url when new commits are pushed to an existing branch? If possible what would be the corresponding configuration in Eclipse or github repository?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The URL should always follow the pattern

```
https://github.com/my-username/my-repo/pull/new/my-branch-name
```

It should not be linked to Eclipse, just to what GitHub is expecting to open a new PR.

Or, in more details as seen in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/devongovett/10399980):

```
https://github.com/$to_user/$repo/pull/new/$to_user:$to_branch...$from_user:$from_branch
```

---

The [OP Dom RC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5271187/dom-rc) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75968440/how-to-return-pull-request-url-when-commit-changes-to-github-using-eclipse/75968615#comment134108274_75968615) to [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) as a way to get the URL generated by the PR creation process.

Example:

```bash
# Create a pull request using flags
~/Projects/my-project$ gh pr create --title "Pull request title" --body "Pull request body"
http://github.com/owner/repo/pull/1
```

Comment: Hi VonC, thanks for your response, I'm doing something similiar using GitHub CLI.

Comment: @DomRC Great, let us know here, in this page, when you get something working.

Comment: yes, of course, this worked for me: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create